Python virtual machine and bytecode
I am trying to fully understand the structure of PYC file. But I can't understand how FLAG_REF works and what it affects, its meaning.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/marshal.c#L952
The code I used:
hello_world = “Hello, world!”
print(hello_world)

To create the PYC file, I used Python 3.6.8. Here is the disassembled PYC file:
330d 0d0a # magic number
7ae2 4966 # timestamp
3100 0000 # file size

e3 # TYPE_CODE = 'c'
0000 0000 # argcount
0000 0000 # kwonlyargcount
0000 0000 # nlocals 
0200 0000 # stacksize
4000 0000 # flags

73 1000 0000 # TYPE_STRING = 's' and size = 16

6400 5a00 6501 6500 
8301 0100 6401 5300 # code

 0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Hello, world!')
 2 STORE_NAME               0 (hello_world)
 4 LOAD_NAME                1 (print)
 6 LOAD_NAME                0 (hello_world)
 8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
10 POP_TOP
12 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
14 RETURN_VALUE

 
2901 # TYPE_TUPLE = '(' and size = 1

7a0d # TYPE_SHORT_ASCII = 'z' and size = 13

48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21 - const 'Hello, world!'

4e # TYPE_NONE = 'N'

2902 # TYPE_TUPLE = '(' and size = 2

5a0b # TYPE_SHORT_ASCII_INTERNED = 'Z' and size = 11

68 65 6c 6c 6f 5f 77 6f 72 6c 64 # name 'hello_world'

da05 # TYPE_SHORT_ASCII_INTERNED da xor FLAG_REF(0x80) = 'Z' and size = 5

70 72 69 6e 74 # name 'print'

a900 # TYPE_SMALL_TUPLE = ')' and size = 0

7202 0000 00 # TYPE_REF = 'r'
7202 0000 00 # TYPE_REF = 'r'

fa0a # TYPE_SHORT_ASCII fa xor FLAG_REF(0x80) = 'z' and size = 10

65 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 2e 70 79 # filename 'example.py'

da08 # TYPE_SHORT_ASCII_INTERNED da xor FLAG_REF(0x80) = 'Z' and size = 8

3c 6d 6f 64 75 6c 65 3e # name '<module>'

0100 0000 # firstlineno = 1

7302 0000 # TYPE_STRING = 's' and size = 2

0004 01


FLAG_REF is used to put an object in the refs list. The objects in the refs list can then be references with a TYPE_REF record (which is a long int). For object with subobjects (e.g. list, dictionaries, ...) this happen before the subobjects are processed. I don't know Python internals well enough to give you an example of why one would want or wouldn't want to put an object in the reference list.

Can you repost your question with all the disassembled code in a single code block?

@Barmar did it.
